# Building an Identity Management System using Microsoft Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, federated-identity, accesscontrolservice, identity-management

I'm looking to build an identity management system with role based access control using Microsoft azure and .net.

I was just wondering if anyone could provide some pointers about it. I want to setup authentication, with access control depending on a users role such as admin.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

http://identityserver.codeplex.com/